# Chrome renders WebM Video "darker" than other browsers / media players

Tags: ffmpeg, color, vp9, rendering

Not sure if this is the correct community, but I have a question about video encoding and decoding.

I have a video that gets served in MP4 or WebM formats, depending on browser support. I noticed that in chrome, the WebM is noticeably darker than when viewing the files locally in VLC, or even another browser such as Firefox:

#### Chrome

[image: Chrome WebM vs MP4]

#### Firefox

[image: Firefox WebM vs MP4]

The original issue was with videos that I was re-encoding myself with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2M output.webm
```

I thought it might be related to the CLI options I was passing in, so I tried playing around with some other [encoding option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) (such as using Constant Quality (CQ) mode and two-pass encoding) but still saw the brightness differences in Chrome. After that, I noticed these same issues on media that was automatically encoded from [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), and I figured if I am seeing the differences there, it probably doesn't have anything to do with my encoding option flags.

Before I go too much down the rabbit hole here, is there anything I can control with this? Or is this just an issue with the decoder Chrome happens to be using (which is different that what VLC or Firefox is using).

Comment: If you disable hardware video decode in Chrome, is the rendering still different?

Comment: Huh, that does fix it! Navigating to `chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode`, the option was set to **Enable** (which I think means it was using hardware video decoding, the option name is a bit confusing...). Setting that to **Disable** and then relaunching Chrome, and the WebM video displays the same as the MP4. So it seems like a bug with GPU decoding?

Comment: Yes, either the decoder isn't passing along the colorimetry info or the renderer in that pipeline isn't acting on it. See existing issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=851216

Comment: I tried lookup up a relevant chromium bug earlier but didn't come across that one. That looks to be exactly the issue I'm seeing! Thanks for all your help.